# Find the smallest number p for which the equation $\cos (p\sin (x))=\sin(p\cos (x))$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the smallest number p for which the equation $\cos (p\sin
> (x))=\sin(p\cos (x))$ has a solution.

x belongs to $[0,2\pi] $

Any hints for this please.Don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you mean the smallest $p>0$ for which the equation has a solution in $x$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter sorry.Corrected it

Comment: Isn't the answer practically already in the answer of your previous question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803639/show-that-cos-sin-theta-sin-cos-theta)?

Comment: Eh :-P....you noticed that before I did :-)..thanks BTW...got it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\cos(p\sin x)=\sin (p\cos x)$$
$$\implies \cos (p\sin x)=\cos(\pi/2-p\cos x)$$
$$\implies p\sin x=2k\pi+\pi/2-p\cos x$$
Where $k \in \mathbb Z$
$$\implies p(\sin x+\cos x)=(4k+1)\pi/2$$
For finding smallest $p$, $k=0$,
$$\implies p(\sin x+\cos x)=\pi/2$$
Now, $\sin x+\cos x\leq \sqrt {2}$,
$$\implies p \geq \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}$$

Comment: I think there is a mistake while transiting from second to third step.The solution should be given by  $2k\pi+ $ or $2k\pi-$ .You didn't take the negative sign.

Comment: When $p=\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}$, the equation is solved by $x=\pm\frac\pi4+2k\pi$.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta $k$ can be negative as well, so the $2k\pi-$case happens when $k<0$

Comment: If $x$ solves the equation, so does $-x$. So we can, without loss of generality, replace $x$ by $-x$ (and $k$ by $-k$) in that case to turn it into the $2k\pi+$ version. @SanchayanDutta (Graphing confirms that $\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}$ is indeed the answer.)

Comment: I have a doubt.Why did you take k=0, k could be negative as well right? So lower bounds should be possible for p...

Comment: @SanchayanDutta good question, as for that I think the question should mention "positive $p$" if there isn't the condition that $p>0$, then it's unbounded. (I can take $k \rightarrow -\infty $)

Comment: Right.But however your answer is indeed excellent.Thanks :)